# how to resolve "java.util.zip.ZipException:duplicate entry: org/apache/xmlbeans/xml/stream/Location.class" issue while hosting springboot in tomcat 10

Tags: java, spring-boot, jakarta-ee, java-ee-6, tomcat10

I am trying to host spring boot rest api in Apache Tomcat 10, but it is not getting hosted, I had placed my spring boot application in webapps-javaee folder, as tomcat 10 default support jakartaee

When I checked logs I am getting this err

> 23-Mar-2022 19:48:49.103 SEVERE [Catalina-utility-2] org.apache.tomcat.jakartaee.Migration.migrateArchiveStreaming Failed to migrate archive [webService-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-exec.war]. Using the "-zipInMemory" option may help.
> java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: org/apache/xmlbeans/xml/stream/Location.class
> at java.util.zip.ZipOutputStream.putNextEntry(Unknown Source)
> at org.apache.tomcat.jakartaee.Migration.migrateArchiveStreaming(Migration.java:228)
> at org.apache.tomcat.jakartaee.Migration.migrateStream(Migration.java:289)
> at org.apache.tomcat.jakartaee.Migration.migrateArchiveStreaming(Migration.java:229)
> at org.apache.tomcat.jakartaee.Migration.migrateStream(Migration.java:289)
> at org.apache.tomcat.jakartaee.Migration.migrateFile(Migration.java:200)
> at org.apache.tomcat.jakartaee.Migration.execute(Migration.java:166)
> at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.migrateLegacyApp(HostConfig.java:1298)
> at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$MigrateApp.run(HostConfig.java:2048)
> at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
> at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
> at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
> at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(Unknown Source)
> at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.migrateLegacyApps(HostConfig.java:1260)
> at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:471)
> at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.check(HostConfig.java:1757)
> at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:316)
> at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:123)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.backgroundProcess(ContainerBase.java:1162)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1365)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1369)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.run(ContainerBase.java:1347)
> at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
> at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(Unknown Source)
> at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(Unknown Source)
> at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
> at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
> at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
> at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
> at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

my Spring boot application is working fine in tomcat 9, but for tomcat 10 it is giving this error

Answer (score 1):

You have to convert the war file manually, go to https://tomcat.apache.org/download-migration.cgi and download the migration tool, then run the command `java -jar jakartaee-migration-1.0.0-shaded.jar -zipInMemory oldFile.war newFile.war`, the **-zipInMemory** option will take care of duplicated files in your war file, then you can put the new war file directly in the webapps folder.